# Do I need to put comma in this context

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, punctuation, grammaticality-in-context

This is my sentence

> XXXX is an *Ontology Predicate* with *xsd:float* data type range that indicates an optional weight for the items that the context is applied on if the time in which they are being recommended is inside the Recommendation Date Range. The value should be less than 1.

I am writing an information system report

That sentence contains many domain-specific terms such as Ontology Predicate, xsd:float, data type range, context, Recommendation Date Range ..

So I am sorry for that.

My question is do I need to put comma **if the time in which they....** or not?

Comment: Yes, a comma should come before **if:** _XXXX is an Ontology Predicate with xsd:float data type range that indicates an optional weight for the items that the context is applied on, if the time in which they are being recommended is inside the Recommendation Date Range._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is applied **on, if** the time in which they

This is an [appositive](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/commas/commas-with-appositives/) that finishes the sentence, so the comma belongs after on.

Comment: Can you you tell the questioner to what referent "This" refers? Also, _appositive_ is a valuable term here and warrants some explanation. Remember, many ELL visitors are not fluent in English!

Answer (score 0):

A comma here would improve readability. However the sentence here is starting to get too long, with too many subclauses. It may be time to consider "refactoring".

Consider, for example:

> XXXX is an Ontology Predicate with xsd:float data type range. The data type indicates an optional weight for the items on which the context is applied. However, the data type is ignored if the time in which they are being recommended is outside the Recommendation Date Range.

Comment: you changed the meaning

Comment: Which implies that the sentence was unclear, and therefore should be rewritten.